# WCF server/client count of clients

Tags: c#, wcf, client

I made server/ client application in WCF.
How get count of connected clients? And how can I send to everyone client oder job? For example: Serwer send to everyone client other numbers to add.

```
Client1 - 1+2=3
Client2 - 1+3=4
Client3 - 1+4=5
```

And sent result to server, which add everyone result from clients I return value (12).

My simple application:

/////edited /////

server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Interface;

namespace WCFapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Klienci cust = new Klienci();
            cust.Connect();
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Interface;

namespace WCFapp
{
     [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
class Klienci : IMessage
{
    private static List<ImessageCallback> subscribers =
        new List<ImessageCallback>();

    public void lista()
    {
        string nm = Console.ReadLine();
        if (nm == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number of conected clients: " + subscribers.Count());
            funkcja();

        }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
            typeof(Klienci), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000")))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessage),
                new NetTcpBinding(), "ISubscribe");

            try
            {
                host.Open();
                lista();
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Subscribe()
    {
        try
        {
            ImessageCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ImessageCallback>();
            if (!subscribers.Contains(callback))
                subscribers.Add(callback);
            Console.WriteLine("Client is conected ({0}).", callback.GetHashCode());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool Unsubscribe()
    {
        try
        {
            ImessageCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ImessageCallback>();
            if (subscribers.Contains(callback))
                subscribers.Remove(callback);
            Console.WriteLine("Client is unconected ({0}).", callback.GetHashCode());
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void funkcja()
    {
        int a = 1; int b = 3;
        subscribers.ForEach(delegate(ImessageCallback callback)
        {
            if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("a= {0} , b= {1}", a, b);
            callback.klient_licz(a, b);
            a++;
            b++;
            }
        });

    }

    public void polacz(int S)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", S);
    }
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;


namespace Interface
{
     [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ImessageCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMessage
{
    [OperationContract]
    void funkcja();

    [OperationContract]
    void polacz(int S);

    [OperationContract]
    bool Subscribe();

    [OperationContract]
    bool Unsubscribe();

}
[ServiceContract]
public interface ImessageCallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    void klient_licz(int a, int b);
}
```

}

Client:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Interface;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            clients cl = new clients();
            if (cl.Conect() == true)
            {
                string tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                while (tmp != "EXIT")
                {
                    cl.SendMessage(tmp);
                    tmp = Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }
             cl.Close();
             Environment.Exit(0);
       }
   }
}
```

.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Interface;

namespace Client
{
    class clients : ImessageCallback, IDisposable
    {
        IMessage pipeProxy = null;
        public bool Conect()
        {
            DuplexChannelFactory<IMessage> pipeFactory =
                new DuplexChannelFactory<IMessage>(
                    new InstanceContext(this),
                    new NetTcpBinding(),
                    new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000/ISubscribe"));
            try
            {
                pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
                pipeProxy.Subscribe();
               return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }

        }

        public void Close()
        {
            pipeProxy.Unsubscribe();
        }


        public void klient_licz(int a, int b)
        {
            int S = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum= {0}", S);
            pipeProxy.polacz(S); //ERROR
        }

    }
}
```

I edited code. Now I get exception in pipeproxy.polacz(S); function ;/

`This operation would deadlock because the reply cannot be received until the current Message completes processing. If you want to allow out-of-order message processing, specify ConcurrencyMode of Reentrant or Multiple on CallbackBehaviorAttribute.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the servers responsablity to cache a list of clients.  Typically this will be a List of client call back interfaces:

```
List<IClientCallback> clients;
```

Typically you fill this from an incoming client call (often in a specific server method like "RegisterClient" - but could be any incoming call on server):

```
IClientCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();              
if (!clients.Contains(callback))
    clients.Add(callback);
```

To manage broadcast to clients you want a generic method to call back a particualr method on all clients in clients list:

```
void CallbackAllClients(Action<IClientCallback> action) {
    for (int i=clients.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        IClientCallback callback = clients[i];
        if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened) {
            try {
                action(callback);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                clients.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        else
            clients.RemovaAt(i);
    }
}
```

You can call that from server code to broadcast a client callback to all clients as:

```
void SomeServerSideEventHandler(MyObject my_obj) {
    CallbackAllClients(client => client.MyObjectChanged(my_obj));
}
```

Where `MyObjectChanged` is a method on the client call back interface `IClientCallback`.
That should get you most of the way.

Comment: I have a little problem to understand this. I make new interface `IClientCallback` in Interface. In server I make a new `class klient : IClientCallback` and make new method ` void RegistryClient()` where I put `List<IClientCallback> clients;` and this method - `IClientCallback callback = .... ` after that I put into Client `RegistryClient()` method. My understanding is correctly? Sorry for my english... I have problem to write what I have in my head.

Comment: IClientCallback is for server callback on your client.  It should be implimented by client or an object in client.  Once the server has a ref to an IClientCallback for a particular client it can contact the client via that interface.  The server impliments RegisterClient.  At connection the client call RegisterClient on server interface.  The server side implimentation of this stores the clients ICientCallback interface in list.  I think you need to read up a little on WCF callbacks.  BTW a server with a call back interface will require a duplex transport eg wsDualHttpBinding or NetTCPBinding

Comment: I read about callback, made some examples. I edited my all code. But now i get exception in function pipeProxy.polacz(S);
`This operation would deadlock because the reply cannot be received until the current Message completes processing. If you want to allow out-of-order message processing, specify ConcurrencyMode of Reentrant or Multiple on CallbackBehaviorAttribute.`

Comment: Without this function it work fine, but I don't now how to send back result to server without this function... ;/

Comment: I suggest you pose that as a separate question (the answer is straight forward but its not really the place to give it in a commnet).  Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: I made new post, as you suggest.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254983/wcf-server-client-callbacks-reply-from-client-to-server